# Align table to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="text-center" style="align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <table style="border: 1rem;">
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td></tr>
        
        
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to align my table to center how should I do it.
I tried `class=text-center`, `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you added as style is fine. But you missed `display: flex;` for the container style.

`align-items: center; justify-content: center;` works only with `display: flex;`

The default `display` value for a `div` will be `block`. This why your solution failed to work.

Please find a working fiddle.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <table style="border: 1rem;">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox. To make any container flex use display: flex

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">

 ... table
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center it using "margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" but note that in your case it will center it in the div in which you have the table so you have to make it bigger if you want it in the center of the screen.

Something like this:

```html
<div class="text-center" style="width:100%">
  <table style="border: 1rem;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div>
 <table style="border: 1px solid orange; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tr><th>Id</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center">
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).